# Homebrew: untar anywhere and install formula: Error: The following directories are not writable by your user

Tags: homebrew

Following [the official Homebrew installation instructions to "untar anywhere"](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#untar-anywhere):

```
$ homebrew_dir="$HOME"/homebrew_for_lunch_and_learn
$ mkdir "$homebrew_dir" && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C "$homebrew_dir"
```

Then attempting to build on top of these instructions for convenience:

```
$ sudo ln -s "$homebrew_dir"/bin/brew /usr/local/bin/lunchbrew
```

Then attempting to install something:

```
$ lunchbrew install python3
...
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
...
```

Or something else:

```
$ lunchbrew install vim
...
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$ ~/homebrew_for_lunch_and_learn/bin/brew install python3
(success...)
```

or this:

```
$ alias lunchbrew="~/homebrew_for_lunch_and_learn/bin/brew"
$ lunchbrew install vim
(success...)
```

Why this works:

It appears that Homebrew cares about the directory of the symlink. The symlink lives at `/usr/local/bin/lunchbrew` in `/usr/local/`. That appears to be why it wants the `/usr/local/` directories to be writable.